# Read connection string from external XML file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, connection-string, .net-4.8

In my ASP.NET MVC project (on .NET 4.8), I have a `web.config` with this working connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SystemConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Server=10.10.10.10; Port=1000; Database=SampleDB; User Id=user1; Password=aaa;" 
         providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I'm trying to remove it from `web.config`, the idea is to place this into a local XML file, therefore avoiding push this information to the cloud repo.

I've made this XML (without `providerName="Npgsql"` as will I mention later):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SystemConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Server=10.10.10.10; Port=1000; Database=SampleDB; User Id=user1; Password=aaa;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've created this code:

```
public class SystemEntities : DbContext
{
    private static SystemEntities instance;

    public static SystemEntities Instance()
    {
        lock (typeof(SystemEntities))
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new SystemEntities();

        return instance;
    }

    public SystemEntities() : base(nameOrConnectionString: GetConnectionString())
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    private static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string filename = "ConnectionStrings.xml";

        // Get the path to the XML file containing connection strings
        string documentPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keysFolder"]; //keysFolder is set at web.config
        string xmlFilePath = Path.Combine(documentPath, filename);

        if (!File.Exists(xmlFilePath))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Error: file not found");

        // Load the XML file
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(documentPath + filename);

        // Retrieve the connection string by name
        string connectionString = doc.Descendants("add")
            .Where(a => a.Attribute("name")?.Value == "SystemConnectionString")
            .Select(a => a.Attribute("connectionString")?.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Error: connection strings not found");

        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

When I try the code above to connect to postgres database, I get this error:

> 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.10.10.10", user "user1", database "template1", no encryption

It seems to me that the connection string is not correct, therefore causing this. Also, if I change at `pg_hba.conf` the database to `all` then I can connect to the database.

Reviewing this code I did notice that `providerName="Npgsql"` was not included in the connection string obtained from XML file, probably contributing to this issue. I've tried to add `Npgsql` to the string, without success.

Can someone please comment on this?

Comment: are you sure the normal connection string approach works? that errors do sound like postgres refues your connection due to config mishap (e.g. wrong IP being listened).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have multiple connection strings in your project and you only want some of them in an external file. But if all of the connection strings (or only this one in total) are in the external file, there's no need to write code that reads this file manually. ASP.NET supports splitting up a `web.config` file in multiple files using the `configSource` attribute. In your example your `web.config` would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.xml" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The `ConnectionStrings.xml` will include a root element of `connectionStrings` which will add the connection string from your example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SystemConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Server=10.10.10.10; Port=1000; Database=SampleDB; User Id=user1; Password=aaa;" 
        providerName="Npgsql" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Source: [The ultimate guide to connection strings in web.config](https://blog.elmah.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-connection-strings-in-web-config/#specify-connection-strings-in-another-file)